# tippy.js doesn't work after being imported

Tags: javascript, html

I installed tippy.js using npm and then it tried to import it into my .js file ,but I face an error.

 
HTML

```
<button id="my-button">btn</button>
<script type="module" src="./script.js"></script>
```

JS

```
import tippy from 'tippy.js';
import 'tippy.js/dist/tippy.css';

tippy('#my-button', {
    content: "github",
    arrow: true,
});
```

Note that I have checked the dependencies and made sure that the package is installed successfully.

 
Error:
[image]

Comment: Please don't post picture of errors, code [ask]

Comment: I'm guessing you aren't using any "development setup" like parcel or vite. By using npm packages you are expected to use a bundler (there are ongoing efforts to avoid it, but I would say still pretty rough, like https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/31944). I'd recommend you to either adopt follow the [CDN installation of tippy](https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/v6/getting-started/#2-cdn) or adopt one of the above setups (which take care of taking npm packages and converting them to normal JS browsers have no issues with).

Comment: @yuriy636 you think webpack can help me solvet this?